# Highlight a particular word of a sentence

Tags: c#, regex

For to highlight a input string I done the following workaround

```
 string input = "This is my text";
 string pattern = "tex.";// Added Regx special charactor
 string replacement = string.Format("<strong>{0}</strong>", "$0");

 var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern,replacement , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The above result is `This is my <strong>text</strong>`

I am expecting to match the input **only if the pattern is 'text' not 'tex.'or any special charactors.** 
Is there any way to do the same?

Here I added the dotnetfiddle link for better understanding 
 https://dotnetfiddle.net/8AR0n9

For better understanding

> I am expecting to escape the special charactors behaviour in
>   Regx.Replace or any alternative way to do this?

Comment: Change your pattern to `"text"` if you only want to match that exact string.

Comment: It is just an example, the pattern may be any thing..

Comment: Question requirement is unclear. Do you have more examples of what should happen and what should not?

Comment: Are you saying if your input is: `This is my text, tex.`, then the result should be: `This is my <strong>text</strong>, tex.` instead of `This is my <strong>text</strong>, <strong>tex.</strong>`?

Comment: Actually, When I used Regx.Replace, the special charactors in pattern also used for matching the input. I need to avoid that.
like `pattern = tex.` should not match text

Comment: Then why are you using `Regex.Replace`? Why not just normal replace?

Comment: Yes, If I use normal string.Replace, then how can i match input and pattern case insensitive way?

Comment: @LMK Then **this** is your true problem :)

Comment: Yes, I think its better to post another question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Regex.Escape()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string input = "This is my text";
string pattern = "tex.";// Added Regx special charactor
string replacement = string.Format("<strong>{0}</strong>", "$0");

var result = Regex.Replace(input, Regex.Escape(pattern), replacement, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Placement of the function can be done when creating the pattern instead too:

```
string input = "This is my text";
string pattern = Regex.Escape("tex.");// Added Regx special charactor
string replacement = string.Format("<strong>{0}</strong>", "$0");

var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

If you print `pattern` after it went through the `Regex.Escape` function, you will see that it has become `tex\.`

Answer (score 1):

Seems too obvious, so I may be missing something, but just change your pattern to the exact text you want to match:

```
string input = "This is my text";
string pattern = "text";
string replacement = string.Format("<strong>{0}</strong>", "$0");

var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern,replacement , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: I am expecting to escape the special charactors behaviour in Regx.Replace or any alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Because the period('.') stands for any character. So I think, you should point out exactly what will be able to follow your 'tex'.

Here is my try.

```
    string input = "This is my text, tex.";
    string pattern = "tex([a-zA-Z]\\d*|\\d[a-zA-Z]*)";      
    string replacement = string.Format("<strong>{0}</strong>", "$0");       
    var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern,replacement , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);       
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

And the result;

```
     This is my <strong>text</strong>, tex.
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you right what u need is

```
tex[a-zA-Z] // if there is only one char expected
```

or

```
tex[a-zA-Z]*  // if more than one char is expected
```